# If else condition match statements not working inside shell of jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, if-statement, jenkins-pipeline

I have below statement in one of the steps in Jenkinsfile

```
 steps {
sh '''
file=/sql/common/file1.sql
echo $file
if ["$file" = *"/common"* ]; then
  echo "changes found in common directory "
fi
'''
}
```

For some reason shell is not working properly inside jenkinsfile. how do we
compare strings in shell in Jenkinsfile? do we have any specific syntax for these? Jenkins give error if I use `==` operator to compare the strings.
My assumption was shell should work same way in Jenkinsfile once we declare it inside `sh '''`. Is that not the case?

Comment: /sql/common/file1.sql is not equal to "/common" and so you will never get the message.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Actually, I want to check for pattern (contains '/common/ ')and == operator is not working there which we use in shell.

Comment: You need to use =~ then

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.. if [  "$file" = ~ .*"/common/".* ]; getting below error in jenkins  [: /root: unexpected operator

Comment: You are missing a space after `[`.

Comment: Thanks. Even with space it doesnt work. I got it working using grep as mentioned in below answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ["$file"
> ```

is invalid. There must be a space between `[` and the argument. `[` is a command.

> ```
> if [ "$file" = *"/common"* ];
> ```

doesn't mean what you think it does. `*"/common"*` undergoes *filename expansion*, so it is replaced by a list of files that match the pattern. Because there are most probably many files that match the filename expansion, `[` program exits with some kind of a a syntax error.

If you want to match a string against a pattern in POSIX shell, either use grep with a *regular expression*:

```
if printf "%s\n" "$file" | grep -q '.*/common.*'; then
```

or use `case` with *glob*:

```
if case "$file" in *"/common"*) true; ;; *) false; ;; esac; then
```

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk , This is what I was looking for, grep condition worked for me.
In the first cast even with space that condition didnt work in jenkinsfile shell. Thanks again